# Cast data of type Any to Array of strings in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So in working on an app using swift and firebase but i have an issue, i have a table view where i add in the data as dates but when i retrieve them, i want them ordered in a way by the time i added them in. so last item will be at the last index. 
Basically i retrieve a data block as type any

```
Optional({
    "-Ly6Njj9vNH_T9umxDwS" = "01-08-2020";
    "-Ly6U4vzEAGvIC0Yblnl" = "12-08-2020";
    "-Ly6U7_91jW5tajpX7k0" = "11-08-2020";
    "-Ly6UG6HYqTMq1NaRehI" = "10-08-2020";
})
```

so here you can see they are numbered correclty frim top to bottom but when i try to put them into an array using

```
data as? [String]
```

it doesnt work and i can do

```
data as [String: String]
```

but that doesnt keep the order, i know i can add time stamps and such but if i have the data correctly formatted aleady but in a type of Any, there must be a way to cast it into an array

Comment: "i know i can add time stamps and such" Excellent, so do that. The "order" here is only an illusion.

Comment: @matt actually the order is relevant, because the automatically generated IDs have a timestamp component built into them, and they will lexicographically sort in chronological order. Which means the OP can just store a sorted list of those IDs if the intent is to iterate the entries in the intended order.

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered. you have to take the keys and objects of the dictionary and sort them accordingly. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/order_dependent_operations_on_dictionary

Comment: @DougStevenson Brilliant point, thanks. I know nothing about Firebase but, uh, you do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary has no real order; the order of printout is not meaningful and can change. We can reproduce this without reference to firebase:

```
let d : NSDictionary = [
    "-Ly6Njj9vNH_T9umxDwS" : "01-08-2020",
    "-Ly6U4vzEAGvIC0Yblnl" : "12-08-2020",
    "-Ly6U7_91jW5tajpX7k0" : "11-08-2020",
    "-Ly6UG6HYqTMq1NaRehI" : "10-08-2020"
]
print(d)
//{
//    "-Ly6Njj9vNH_T9umxDwS" = "01-08-2020";
//    "-Ly6U4vzEAGvIC0Yblnl" = "12-08-2020";
//    "-Ly6U7_91jW5tajpX7k0" = "11-08-2020";
//    "-Ly6UG6HYqTMq1NaRehI" = "10-08-2020";
//}

let d2 = d as! [String:String]
print(d2)
// ["-Ly6Njj9vNH_T9umxDwS": "01-08-2020", 
   "-Ly6U4vzEAGvIC0Yblnl": "12-08-2020", 
   "-Ly6UG6HYqTMq1NaRehI": "10-08-2020", 
   "-Ly6U7_91jW5tajpX7k0": "11-08-2020"]
```

So if you want an ordered list of pairs you *must* use an array and you *must* order it yourself somehow, presumably using the timestamp. But as a comment says, that order *is* the order of the keys.

```
let arr = Array(d2).sorted {$0.key < $1.key}
print(arr)
//[(key: "-Ly6Njj9vNH_T9umxDwS", value: "01-08-2020"),
// (key: "-Ly6U4vzEAGvIC0Yblnl", value: "12-08-2020"),
// (key: "-Ly6U7_91jW5tajpX7k0", value: "11-08-2020"),
// (key: "-Ly6UG6HYqTMq1NaRehI", value: "10-08-2020")]
```

If all you want is the date strings, just `map` that down to its `value`s. The order is preserved because these are now arrays.

```
let arr2 = arr.map {$0.value}
print(arr2)
// ["01-08-2020", "12-08-2020", "11-08-2020", "10-08-2020"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if the keys scale? lets say i have lots of entries since my key is childByAutoID, will at some point sorting out by keys not work and hence ill have to implement a timestamp/other method?

Comment: I know nothing of Firebase but Doug Stephenson's comment on your question says that the autogenerated keys are in timestamp lexicographical order.

Comment: @JoseCuevas I am going to just add a bit more info. I would not depend on the keys for ordering. While what Doug said in his comments and this answer is (obviously) 100% accurate, there are many times where leveraging them will not work. Suppose you want to get all of the nodes between Date X and Date Y. Or what if you wanted them ordered descending. Or you want to paginate your data? I would suggest storing your dates as strings like this: 20200108, 20201208, 20201108 etc. That will give a lot more control over how much data is being loaded (pagination) and the range/order it's loaded in.